# Injecting userid in DbContext for multi-tenant application

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I am building a multi-tenant application with .net identity. I want each user when they log in to view their own data. I have a user resolver service where i inject httpContextAccessor to try to inject the user id from claims principal from HttpContext.

```
internal sealed class AppUserResolver : IAppUserResolver
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AppUserResolver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    
    public string GetCurrentAppUserId()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.User
            .FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)!;
    }
}
```

Then I inject my service into the DbContext class.

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    private readonly IAppUserResolver _appUserResolver;
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IAppUserResolver appUserResolver)
        : base(options)
    {
        _appUserResolver = appUserResolver;
    }

    public string GetUserId()
    {
        return _appUserResolver.GetCurrentAppUserId();
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserInfoConfiguration(GetUserId()));
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EmailInfoConfiguration(GetUserId()));
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SocialMediaInfoConfiguration(GetUserId()));
    }
}
```

How ever i noticed that the claims where not available when DI container injected DbContext, so instead of getting the claims directly in the DbContext constructor I created a method to get them only when needed.

But the problem is with the OnModleCreating method. This method is only called once when the app starts and EF Core caches the configurations. But in this method I have applied the HasQueryFilter method for some entities, however it get set with an empty string, because when the user tries to log in the claims are null, so the first time the dbContext initializes it gets initialized with null user id ans so does the OnModelCreating.

```
internal sealed class UserInfoConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserInfo>
{
    private readonly string _appUserId;

    public UserInfoConfiguration(string appUserId)
    {
        _appUserId = appUserId;
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserInfo> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("UserInfo");
        
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.HasOne<AppUser>(x => x.AppUser)
            .WithOne(x => x.UserInfo)
            .HasForeignKey<UserInfo>(x => x.AppUserId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasQueryFilter(x => x.AppUserId == _appUserId);
    }
}
```

After the login the claims principal are available with every user actuion BUT the OnModelCreating has already run and been cached. So the queries made after are wrong and bring nonthing as they filter with an mepty string as a user id. Any suggestion on how this would be tackled or should i filter everywhere with user id?

I have also registered HttpContextAccessor and my user resolver service at services registration

```
 serviceCollection.AddHttpContextAccessor();
 serviceCollection.AddScoped<IAppUserResolver, AppUserResolver>();
```

Comment: You have here a good example on how to build a multi-tenancy app https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-multitenant-application/

Comment: This is the example that I followed and I am having the problem i describe above. The OnModelCreating gets initialized with empty userId because when user logs in the claims are null so there is no user id, but the db comntext has to be initialized so that the login method access the users table

Comment: Did u read this? "Usually, tenant setups come from a separate database or a registry system. But we are going to keep it simple by using an appsettings.json configuration file:"

Comment: So you cannot aplly this method of query filtering in the same DbContext  with identity and rest of the tables? The app is an mvc application

Answer (score 0):

implementing a custom service that relies on HttpContextAccessor and injecting it into DbContext seems unnecessary. to me, it seems like you are trying to reinvent the wheel. why not simply use `User` property in the controllers? authorization middleware will automatically populate this property with current user's claims (which is read from cookie if using cookie authn scheme).

You can conveniently retrieve all user claims with `User.Identity.Claims`.
For code reuse. you can implement a helper method like this which you can call from your controllers:

```
    public static string GetCurrentUserName(ClaimsPrincipal user)
        =>
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user?.Identity?.Name) && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        ? user.Identity.Name
        : "";
```

This example simply returns user's name, but you can edit it to return the exact claim you are willing to retrieve.
NOTE: for this approach, you need to register the relevant property as a user claim, so that it is in `AspNetUserClaims` table, which ensures the information will be stored in cookie as a claim.

As an example, here is how you can assign a claim to a user:

```
var someUser = userMgr.FindByNameAsync("JohnWick").Result;
userMgr.AddClaimsAsync(someUser, new Claim[]{
                                        new Claim("Company", "Mercedes")
                                    }).Result;
```

NOTE: this is the claims approach, but you can also choose to use roles (which are also pretty much claims tbh, just slightly less flexible and you use different identity methods). **if you don't want to keep this info in cookie, then you will have to read the property from the database from user table for every request which would not be a performant approach, so I would recommend against that.**

Comment: Every example that shows how ot implement multi-tenancy follows that specific approach, so i don't think anybody tries to reinvent the wheel. The problem apperas because the firest time the dbContext is injected, in gets initialized with empty string because at that time the user tries to log in, there is not additional appuserid. Maybe injecting in evcery controller the user id is the only approach here

Comment: @athagiorgos injecting user id to every controller? I'm not sure what you mean. as I explained in my answer, `User` property is automatically initialized by Authorization middleware, which is accessible inside all controllers. This property contains information about the current user.

Comment: trying to instantiate DbContext with current user's ID every request is not the way to go about this. I understand you are having problems with service container, but you really don't need to do what you are trying to do. I can help you fix that specific problem, but it would not be a proper solution, and it would likely cause more issues down the road. you need to access current user info, and I explained the appropriate approach. please have a try at my suggestion.

Comment: I am using your logic in your example. That was my first thought as well. I created an extension method to return the user id from httpcontext and it is working. It's just that with this approach i have to chain a .Where() in every linq query i make to the db and i just wanted to wrap this arounf the HasQueryFilter method.

Answer (score 0):

We do something really similar but are able to accomplish it with using an `IPrincipal` as a ClaimsPrincipal. We are using .NET 6

**Program.cs**

*Register the IPrincipal to get what the User from the HttpContext. Also wires up EF Core*

```
// Register the IPrincipal to the delegate here to get the logged in ClaimsPrincipal user
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPrincipal>((sp) => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);

// Register EF Context
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>((options) =>
{
   options.UseSqlServer(r => r.UseNetTopologySuite());
});
```

**AppDataContext.cs**

*DI injects the IPrincipal into the AppDataContext. There is some custom code in here for different ways we deal with the tenant's ID and get the connection string, but I think you get the idea. The point is that the OnConfiguring will set the connectionstring.*

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
       private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _principal;
       private readonly int? _shardID;
       private readonly IDbConnectionService _dbConnectionService;

       public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options, 
           IPrincipal principal, 
           IDbConnectionService dbConnectionService, 
           int? shardID = null) : base(options)
       {
           _shardID = shardID;
           _principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)principal;
           _dbConnectionService = dbConnectionService;
       }

       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
       {
           int? shardID = _shardID ?? _principal.GetShardID();
           if (shardID.HasValue)
           {
               optionsBuilder
                   .UseSqlServer(_dbConnectionService.SqlConnection(shardID.Value), (x) => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
           }
       }
}
```

**Usage in Class**

```
    public class RepositoryDependencyProvider : IRepositoryDependencyProvider
    {
        private readonly AppDataContext appDataContext;
        private readonly ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

        public RepositoryDependencyProvider(
            AppDataContext appDataContext
            )
        {
            this.appDataContext = appDataContext;
        }

        public void GetData()
        {
            var foo = appDataContext.MyEntity.First();
        }

    }
```

Note that the GetShardID is just an Extension method that we use to get the tenant id out of the custom claims:

```
        public static int? GetShardID(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            return principal.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == SHARD_ID_KEY).ToList().Select(x => (int?)int.Parse(x.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```